# Can't create a docker image. A compatible SDK version for global.json version: [2.2.106] from [/app/global.json] was not found

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

This is my first time using docker so I am probably doing some things wrong. I am trying to dockerize my asp.net core microservice. I was following this tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/. There I found this dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY FlightManagement.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FlightManagement.dll"]
```

When I try the following command:

```
docker build -t flightmanagement .
```

I get the following output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.949MB
Step 1/10 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
2.2: Pulling from dotnet/core/sdk
6f2f362378c5: Already exists 
494c27a8a6b8: Already exists 
7596bb83081b: Already exists 
372744b62d49: Already exists 
29ec75cd6459: Pull complete 
abb902ce071b: Pull complete 
eaac80d34a7a: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:f0617d5f2241cc964d0ec4314f3920b843e9737c879d94fdf827ed749bf17cc2
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
 ---> 155911c343f3
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 5733374f2db1
Removing intermediate container 5733374f2db1
 ---> c954daddd668
Step 3/10 : COPY *.csproj ./
 ---> fac826a55fbe
Step 4/10 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in b6261ef4d8d5
  Restore completed in 2 sec for /app/FlightManagement.csproj.
Removing intermediate container b6261ef4d8d5
 ---> 9500077ee638
Step 5/10 : COPY . ./
 ---> d03756b83149
Step 6/10 : RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
 ---> Running in c7a8138ebbbf
A compatible SDK version for global.json version: [2.2.106] from [/app/global.json] was not found
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o out' returned a non-zero code: 145
```

I tried multiple tutorials on dockerizing an asp.net core application but they al seem to give the same error. I hope someone is ably to help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2`, it default .net core sdk is `2.2.300`.

But, you create a project with specifying the sdk is `2.2.106` by `global.json`.

Change your global.json like below:

```
{
    "sdk": {
        "version": "2.2.300"
    }
}
```